# Partial SSR rendering of a page using React

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering

**Situation:**

We are using SSR with react for our anonymous users and all is working well. We'd like to move to SSR for authenticated users, however, we don't yet have the testing in place to prove that we are 'thread safe' with our users data.

**Problem:**

I've been investigating a compromise where we use SSR to do a 'partial render' of our header, footer and other static elements. This means that we can deliver the user something to look at, whilst we client render the page, improving the user's experience with out handling user specific data (as we aren't ready to do this yet).

I've built everything out and it all works beautifully. However, React plays nice with but really doesn't like:

a) Having SSRed content in the entry point of the DOM *(calling render, not hydrate, because we are client rendering not hydrating)*

```
Warning: render(): Calling ReactDOM.render() to hydrate server-rendered markup will stop working in React v17. Replace the ReactDOM.render() call with ReactDOM.hydrate() if you want React to attach to the server HTML.
```

b) The SSRed content not exactly matching the client rendered content.

```
Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <div> in <div>.
```

For this situation, the docs suggest a two stage rendering approach where we render the static stuff in the client first, then swap it over. This isn't practical for us, as the amount work would mean that we go full SSR and solve the testing problem instead of this halfway house.

Is there a way I can tell React not to worry about the differences in DOM and to replace it all anyway?

Or do I give up and work on the proper SSR solution?

Answer (score 0):

In the end, we rendered into another div and then is flipped over with CSS when React renders in to the DOM. This works very cleanly.